# CosmosDB - Create Index

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have created a new collection in CosmosDB and I'm trying to create my first index.

I run the following script:

```
db.getCollection("mycoll").createIndex({ "UniqueId": 1 }, { "name": "udx_mycoll_UniqueId", "unique": true });
```

And it produces the response:

```
{
    "_t" : "CreateIndexesResponse",
    "ok" : 1,
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 3,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 4
}
```

Which looks promising, but when I run the query:

```
db.mycoll.getIndexes();
```

No indexes are found. I tried running it in Compass too, and I get an error when I switch to the indexes tab:

> '$indexState' is not supported

Anyone able to shed some light on this?

Comment: Checking with the team on this.

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo, but you createIndex on "mycoll", then getIndexes on "woods" which doesn't seem right.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT sorry - that was a typo - the collection name was the same in both when I ran it. I have edited it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if you use [Robo3T client](https://robomongo.org/download).
However, the custom name is not taken into account.

In your case:

```
db.getCollection("mycoll").createIndex({ "UniqueId": 1 }, { "name": "udx_mycoll_UniqueId", "unique": true });
```

you will end up with an index named: **UniqueId_1**